# React component type.name is some abstract letters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

In my app i need to know children.type.name. In my test project i get what i expect

```
const TestChild2 = () => <td>b</td>;
```

[image: Chrome dev tools]

but in my "production" project it is just "n" or "Ez" or some other random letters.

```
import React from 'react'

const InputCell = (props) => {

    console.log('hi');
    return <td>hi</td>;
}

export default InputCell;
```

[image: Chrome dev tools 2]

Why does that happen? I use the same version of browser and same version of react ("react": "^16.13.1")in both projects.

Comment: for production build .They will  create bundle  js and compress the length of code .So that time the will replace the function name with some newly assigned random string . So better call via props instead of the function call name , you can see the different on you image .first one is app.js second is a chunk.js

Comment: @prasanth, so it is impossible to fix for a production version?

Comment: I suggest you pass a prop to that component that identifies it uniquely rather than relying on `prop.children.type.name`.

Comment: oh... ok, thank you

Comment: @goto1 wait i need to pass a class to parent object that then clones this children with needed props. I cannot push any props to this children before i know what type they are. How to do that?

Comment: @AlexandrAccord I don't quite get what you're trying to do but you need to rethink it and do it properly. If you edit your question showing exactly what you need to accomplish I'll have a better chance at suggestion a solution.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does that happen?

This happens because React does this when building the production build. React probably does this to minify the code.

As workaround you can access the name in prod build as well by passing the name as prop/defaultProp.