# Get name of function component (consider prod build)

Tags: reactjs

I would like to get the name of a function component when the component is instantiated and accessible as a child. In dev mode, I can get the name with `element.type.name`. But in the production build, this value is minified, so I can't validate an expected name.

Dev

[image]

Prod

[image]

[In this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61750233/react-component-type-name-is-some-abstract-letters) is suggested to pass the name as prop. But I don't like that approach, since the component should already know what his name is.

So how can I get the name? Is there a magic function or so bound to the object to get the name? Or should I create a feature request to react?

Answer (score 0):

I faced to same problem in my project. I found a solution. You can use displayName with your function

```
export const nameOfFunction = (props) => (
    ...
)
nameOfFunction.displayName = 'nameOfFunction'
```

And than you can call like that:

```
console.log(nameOfFunction.displayName)
```

Result:

```
>>> nameOfFunction
```